# Fixed allocation std::vector

Tags: c++, embedded, allocation

I'm an embedded software developer and as such I can't always use all the nice C++ features. One of the most difficult things is avoiding dynamic memory allocation as it is somewhat universal with all STL containers.

The `std::vector` is however very useful when working with variable datasets. The problem though is that the allocation(e.g. `std::reserve`) isn't done at initialization or fixed. This means that memory fragmentation can occur when a copy occurs.

It would be great to have every vector have an allocated memory space which is the max size the vector can grow to. This would create deterministic behaviour and make it possible to map the memory usage of the microcontroller at compilation time. A call to `push_back` when the vector is at it's max size would create a `std::bad_alloc`.

I have read that an alternative version of `std::allocator` can be written to create new allocation behaviour. Would it be possible to create this kind of behaviour with `std::allocator` or would an alternative solution be a better fit?

I would really like to keep using the STL libraries and amend to them instead of recreating my own vector as I'm more likely to make mistakes than their implementation.

**sidenote #1:**

I can't use `std::array` as 1: it isn't provided by my compiler and 2: it does have a static allocation but I then still have to manage the boundary between my data and buffer inside the `std::array`. This means rewriting a `std::vector` with my allocation properties which is what I'm trying to get away from.

Comment: What stops you from calling `std::vector::reserve` at initialization, yourself?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Many embedded systems don't even have an `operator new` defined. If you call a dynamic allocation function in those systems, it will fail. OTOH, some do have it, but the coding standard requires all allocation to be done at startup, in which case `.reserve()` will work.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That is indeed my solution at this time **but** when taking automotive as an example: dynamic allocations are forbidden because the behaviour needs to be deterministic. Creating a `vector` inside a set space would fix that problem.

Comment: `std::array` is very easy to write yourself.  There only appear to be about 27 functions - and you probably don't need them all.  The "it doesn't support a variable size" is rather harder.

Comment: It is possible to create a tailored allocator, which can be used with standard containers, that allocates memory from a memory pool.   If that memory pool is allocated at program startup, then there is no reallocation after program startup.    Obviously, it is necessary to design the memory pool itself using knowledge of how the containers are used, and redesign the allocator (and how it manages the memory pool) accordingly if usage patterns change.   That is possible, but hardly trivial - particularly if you have developers who expect to resize standard containers arbitrarily.

Comment: You'll eventually realize that all C++ containers offer in this matter is increased complexity, increased dev time and harder maintenance. Just use a linked list with static allocation.

Comment: How would a linked list be better? That would mean using the size of a pointer for **every** element. Which means more `LDR`s to be executed. Also strong disagree as data hiding isn't the same as complexity and longer dev time and harder maintenance are just not true.

Comment: I didn't say that data hiding meant complexity and longer dev time, I said that C++ meant that. The reason being the inevitable code bloat, complexity and meta programming madness that is almost guaranteed to follow. It's simply not a very suitable language for embedded system development. If you have the discipline _not_ to use crap like std::vector, then you can use C++ just fine, but C++ programmers with the discipline needed to not use various pitfall C++ features are very rare.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can implement or reuse boost's [static_vector](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/container/static_vector.html); *A variable-size array container with fixed capacity.*

And also: LLVM's small vector without LLVM dependencies [here](https://github.com/thelink2012/SmallVector). This creates objects at the stack until a compile-time constant is reached, then it moves to the heap.

Answer (score 3):

You can always use a C-style array (same as underlying in `std::array`) as vectors aren't supposed to be static

```
int arr[5]; // static array of 5 integers
```

To have it more useful you can wrap it in a class template to hide the C-style
Example:

```
template<class type, std::size_t capacaty>
class StaticVector {
    private:
        type arr[capacaty];
        std::size_t m_size;
    public:
        StaticVector() : m_size(0) {}

        type at(std::size_t index) {
            if (index >=0 && index < m_size) {
                return arr[index];
            }

            return type();
        }

        void remove(std::size_t index) {
            if (index >=0 && index < m_size) {
                for (std::size_t i=index; i < m_size-1; i++) {
                    arr[i] = arr[i+1];
                }
                m_size--;
            }
        }

        void push_back(type val) {
            if (m_size < capacaty) {
                arr[m_size] = val;
                m_size++;
            }
        }

        std::size_t size() {
            return m_size;
        }
};
```

Example with it in use: https://onlinegdb.com/BkBgSTlZH

Comment: He has said that `new` is not an option

Comment: I want the C++ goodness of a managed class. Going back to a C array would be a major step back. Also I don't want a statically sized array. I want a dynamic container which grows/shrinks its exposed interface inside a static memory space.

Comment: https://www.onlinegdb.com/BkBgSTlZH that's a very rough version with the C-Style as a base, but not exposed, does fill your requirement of "grow/shrink" without new and allocating memory at initialization within a specific static memory space, this does however require you to implement the functions yourself.

Comment: Or... use a static allocated linked list for this purpose. The code you have posted here is ridiculously slow and can't be justified. "I want it to be like vector" isn't a rational argument, "I want fast code" is.

Comment: @Lundin Just to be clear, is it the C-Style array you claim is slow or just the example wrapper code? Also do you have some actual proof/reference for your claims? Because if you do, I'd love to read up on it.

Comment: It's very slow since you move the whole array around. That's a naive algorithm, linked lists exist for a reason. You _can_ implement a static array in quicker ways though, by doing so as a ring buffer. Similarly, you can use a static buffer as a linked list. And so on.

Comment: It should be notes that this wrapper does not work like `std::vector` does. The main issue is that you can't use types that are not default constructible.