# what does the following bit of boost code do?

Tags: c++, boost, embedded, keil

I'm trying to compile parts of the boost library for my STM32. I've used bcp to export the `static_vector`.

> `bcp boost/container/static_vector.hpp .`

I can successfully compile the code and use a `static_vector` as per this code

```
boost::container::static_vector<int,10> vec;
```

But I need to disable this bit of code located inside `boost\container\allocator_traits.hpp:467` before I can successfully compile.

```
template<class T>
   static void priv_construct_dispatch_next(container_detail::false_type, Allocator &, T *p, const ::boost::container::default_init_t&)
   {  ::new((void*)p) T; }
```

When I don't disable that bit code the following error occurs:

```
../Inc/boost/container/allocator_traits.hpp(469): error:  #384: no instance of overloaded "operator new"  matches the argument list
            argument types are: (unsigned int, void *)
     {  ::new((void*)p) T; }
```

I'm using the following defines:

```
BOOST_NO_CXX11_RVALUE_REFERENCES BOOST_NO_ALIGNMENT BOOST_NO_TYPEID BOOST_NO_STD_LOCALE
```

And am using Keil µVision 5 with the "default arm compiler version 5". The boost library is version 1.58.

It seems to me that a definition of `new` is missing in this version of Keil. But I'm unable to determine what that bit of code does, let alone define my own version which fill that missing gap.

So what does that bit of code do and can I implement my own fix?

Comment: It's a placement new operation. It constructs a new object of type `T` at address `p`

Comment: Placement new is part of standard library, but you need to #include <new>  It seems strange that boost would use it without including the header, but maybe it is an oversight.  Or maybe the placement new operator is indeed missing from your standard library and you can provide something.

Comment: @ChrisUzdavinis I am pretty sure STM32 STL doesn't have placement new, as it most likely doesn't support dynamic memory allocation at all. I would be hard-pressed to believe that such a mature library as `static_vector` has an oversight in proper includes.

Comment: It's even weirder. They included it by doing: `#include <boost/container/detail/placement_new.hpp>` with the 'correct' definitions for `new` and `delete` with the comment: `//avoid including <new>` But it didn't resolve correctly in the compiler

Comment: The functions in Boost's placement_new.hpp are different because they take an additional argument of type `boost_container_new_t`. They aren't a replacement for the standard placement new.

Comment: It looks like you're using an old buggy Boost version. The current version doesn't have the code causing this error.

Comment: @interjay you seem to be correct. I've used 1_58 to export these functions as this was easiest available. (had an ubuntu 16.04 vm which can with a simple `apt-get` use `bcp` to export boost libs. So I'll be updating that.

Comment: It will be interesting to see how you get on.  My experience of using Boost on STM32 with armcc 5.x is that it is profligate consumer of the very limited available memory. Actually not my experience; the rather the experience of a colleague (recent graduate) who ignored my doubts (old dinosaur with 30 years of development experience) that the project would fit when implemented with boost, and then had to remove all that work and re-implement it - expensive experiment!

Comment: @Clifford I'm aware of the size of the boost libraries. That's why I only exported the `static_vector`. In fact this question is related to [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56934911/fixed-allocation-stdvector), I'm looking for a static buffer vector for compile time allocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by all above. This is the [placement new operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new).

The problem is the version of boost. Version 1.65 (at least) has fixed this by changing

```
{  ::new((void*)p) T; }
```

into

```
{  ::new((void*)p, boost_container_new_t()) T; }
```

Side note on a comment: Keil does have an implementation inside `<new>` for the placement new operator but this isn't included by boost.
Snippet from `<new>:89`

```
/* Placement new. */
inline void *operator new(std::size_t, void* __ptr) throw() { return __ptr; }
```